# Adobe AIR for iPhone app : can audio streaming play in background?

Tags: iphone, actionscript-3, air, audio-streaming

Can an iphone app developed with Adobe AIR (version 2.6/2.7) play a streaming sound when it is in background ?

Only native application can play in background ?
I have not found a clearly response to this question on documentation.

PS: i'm using the Adobe AS3 class Sound to play a shoutcast streaming.

Comment: Was going to ask the target platform and then saw, sorry.  I'm 99.9999% sure that you cannot play outside of the app.

Answer (score 0):

So far AIR on iPhone doesn't support multitasking, all apps are completely frozen when in background, so no sounds.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, you're out of luck at the moment. However, this feature is currently being tested in the AIR 3 Beta so you can expect it out soon.

Taken from [labs.adobe.com](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/flashplatformruntimes/air3/):

> ### iOS Background Audio Playback Support
>
> Developers can now write multitasking iOS applications that can play audio while in the background, including music or voice chat from a conferencing application.